# Excel Update column based on another column from another sheet

Tags: excel

I've an excel with 2 sheets
In One sheet I've data like below

```
    ID  ID1   Name
    1   101   ABC
    2   202   XYZ
    3   303   MNP
```

In Sheet2 I've data like below

```
ID   ADD
1    LONDON
2    USA
3    CANADA
```

Now I need add one more column in sheet2 and want ID2 corresponding to ID1 from sheet1.

Like

```
   ID   ADD   ID2
   1    LONDON 101
   2    USA    202
   3    CANADA 303
```

Please help.

Comment: Do some research into the `VLOOKUP` function.  Any tutorial will easily show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX(MATCH())`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```